# Path of an SVG file

Tags: java, svg, processing

How to get the attributes inside the path and edit any specific attribute. For example, if I want to change the color of that path for any selected ids. how do i write a code for that in Processing. Please provide an example if possible. I tried using getChildren() but not sure if I doing it right.
This is what i tried to do

> ```
> void setup() {
>   size(1000, 800);
>   background(255);
>   noLoop();
>
>   //loading the map and the csv file
>   baseMap=loadShape("nepalmap.svg");
>   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();
>   for (PShape ps : baseMap.getChildren()) { //get pshape from themap
>     names.add(ps.getName());
>   }
>   
>   location=loadTable("location.csv", "header");
>   for (TableRow row : location.rows()) {
>     String id = row.getString("district");
>     float[] latlon = new float[2];
>     latlon[0]=row.getFloat("Latitude"); 
>     latlon[1]=row.getFloat("Longitude");
>     PShape shape = baseMap.findChild(id);
>     if (shape == null) {
>
>       
>        println("Unfound: " + id );
> ```

I need to be able to get the path using the district name. I will leave an example of what the path of one of the district looks like for better understanding. After finding the district i need to be change the color of the district i want.

Link to the SVG file
https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArCqZlwbF3LRbomDBoJu3Qt0_hA?e=F5GAY1

Thank you

Comment: You may want to add whatever you tried and whatever response you got, any errors, etc.,  in your question.

Comment: I tried using getChild but i am not sure how to use it so for how i just need some ideas to start coding. I havent stated programming it.

Comment: Please provide us anything you have tried so far. Try to think of a more extensive example of the svg as well so that others can understand your problem and can start thinking about a solution.

Comment: Which library are you using? What is the type of `baseMap`?

Comment: @Lelouch you should post nepalmap.svg as well to illustrate the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code the assumption is that each district is a direct child of the root SVG node. This may or may not be true for your SVG.

If you're unsure you can use [findChild()](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PShape.html#findChild-java.lang.String-) instead of `getChild()`.
The difference is findChild will walk through the SVG hierarchy until it finds the child b y that name, if it exists.

**Note** that you have two data sources: SVG and CSV.
Ensure that both use the same names (key sensitive). If they don't match you `findChild()` may return `null` (well done on the the "unfound" check btw!)

Once you have a reference to the district PShape you can try calling [`setFill()`](https://processing.org/reference/PShape_setFill_.html) for example or [`disableStyle()`](https://processing.org/reference/PShape_disableStyle_.html) which disables the SVG style and uses the most recent fill/stroke attributes you've set in Processing.

Comment: I have one last question. is it possible to add a mouse pressed on the district Pshape. For example: if i clicked on that district , it shows the data i want somewhere in the canvas.

Comment: @Lelouch it's not built in, but the functionality can be written with existing PShape functionality. please post another question: it will make it easier for others to find it along with the solution. If this answer was useful vote / mark it as a solution :) (be sure to go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while you're there :) )

Comment: @Lelouch check out `mouseClicked()` and PShape's [`contains(x,y)`](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PShape.html#contains-float-float-) (be careful of what shape type it is, (see getKind()/getFamily()) it is to be able to get a useful result)